# Website formatting going haywire automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dreamweaver

Domain is www.gafep.org

Website ran perfectly fine for a month. Then yesterday I noticed that the formatting is screwed on IE and Mozilla but is working perfectly fine on Chrome. Today morning I found that chrome also has same problem. The footer comes up to the top. The div tags that are supposed to demarcate are overlapping. (I have made a call to footer through php include in all pages)

Most baffling part is I had not made any change to code from my side and the website automatically goes haywire.

Worst part is when I open the backups I had made 10-15 days back when the site was working perfectly, they show the same problem. They were perfectly formatted before, however they all look the same now.

I cant get a hold of why this is happening. I have used Dreamweaver for coding. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the problem is related to browser caching. You said the the site worked fine for a while, then after a period of time it started no to. What likely it happened is that the web browsers cached the good .js and .css files for a period of time (depending on the browser settings), and even if the latests .js/.css files are broken those browsers didn't picked up these files until recently.

This is why you didn't notice the problem before, and this is why the same browser and the same site no longer work, even if before they worked and no changes were made since then.

Comment: Sorted. It was exactly as you mentioned. catching problem. took css folder from the oldest version and uploaded it. Everything is perfect now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Glad I could help. Browser caching of css/js files always poses a challenge.